# Not able to login into Tomcat 7 manager App after configuring ldap authentication

Tags: tomcat, ldap, basic-authentication

I have configured the ldap authentication for my application in Tomcat 7 server.xml. But after this configuration i am not able to login into tomcat manager app. I have configured the roles for manager-gui,manager-script and manager-jmx in tomcat-users.xml. If i am removing the ldap configuration the tomcat manager app works.

I am not able to identify that why this is happening.How i should configure ldap and tomcat manager roles so that they work together.
I have mentioned my files below:

```
    **server.xml**

   // This contains the ldap configuration:

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
    connectionName="CN=BPMptlbindt,OU=WASportal,OU=App Groups,DC=infores,DC=com"
    connectionPassword="re.Doce3" 
    connectionURL="ldap://crpdcw201p.infores.com:3268"
    debug="99" referrals="follow" 
    roleBase="DC=infores,DC=com"
    roleName="CN" 
    roleSearch="(member={0})" 
    roleSubtree="true"
    userBase="DC=infores,DC=com" 
    userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})" 
    userSubtree="true" /> 

    **tomcat-users.xml**

   // This contains the tomcat manager role configuration.

    <tomcat-users>
        <role rolename="manager-gui" />
        <role rolename="manager" />
        <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager,manager-gui" />
        <role rolename="manager-script" />
        <user password="admin" roles="manager-script" username="admin" />
        <role rolename="manager-status " />
        <user password="status" roles="manager-status" username="status" />
        <role rolename="manager-jmx " />
        <user password="jmx" roles="manager-jmx" username="jmx" />
    </tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create roles in LDAP for accessing the manager and then modify the web.xml file for the manager application to use those new role names.